# How to insert a large amount of data into a QListWidget from another thread in qt

Tags: qt, qthread, qlistwidget

I am trying to insert a large amount of data from another thread, but the Gui freezes and the program craches when it's added roughly 50k rows.

I'm using QFuture to call the function from a threadPool

```
QFuture<void> thread = QtConcurrent::run(&Main::ToRunFunction,this);
```

here is my code.

```
void Main::ToRunFunction(){

   QSqlDatabase db = openThreadConnection();
   qry = new QSqlQuery(db);
   qry->prepare("with numbers(number) as (select 1 union ALL SELECT number+1 from numbers limit 3000000)SELECT number from numbers")
  
  if(qry->exec()){
    while(qry->next()){

        qDebug() << qry->value(0).toString();
        QString value = qry->value(0).toString();
        ui->listWidget->addItem(value);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Qt widgets should be used from the GUI thread. What you should do is add new signal and connect a slot to it. The in your own thread emit the signal.

```
// In header
signals:
    void addItem(const QString& item);

slots:
    void onAddItem(const QString& item);

// In cpp
void Main::onAddItem(const QString& item)
{
    ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
}

// Somewhere in cpp
connect(this, &Main::addItem, this, Main::onAddItem);

//In your concurrent code
QString value = qry->value(0).toString();
emit addItem(value);
```